# Writing double quote into csv is resulting in three double quotes

Tags: c#, csv

Iam using dapper to read some values from db and write it into a csv, 
for a particular column I want to write the column with double quoted string

`$"\"{x.Notes}\""`, I have tried this but when I write it into the csv it is resulting in three double quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a normal behaviour.

When a string contains specials characters, such as *separators*, *newlines* or *double quotes*, that string must be wrapped into double quotes. The double quotes are then doubled.

Some examples :

`foo "Hello world" bar` becomes `"foo ""Hello world"" bar"`

`foo "bar"` becomes `"foo ""bar"""`

`"foo"` becomes `"""foo"""`

Comment: is there any way I can get only one double quote?

Comment: This will result an invalid CSV

Comment: You can try it yourself with a [CSV converter](https://www.freeformatter.com/csv-escape.html) with, in example, the string `"foo"`, this will be escaped as `"""foo"""`